# Is it possible to draw gradient effect in background without using image?

Tags: android

> Can i set background gradient without using image using only colors.
>
> please tell me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create online gradient using:-

http://angrytools.com/gradient/

and Put into drawable folder as a xml file

set background as image

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that just by adding colors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#83a4d4"
    android:endColor="#b6fbff"
    android:angle="45"/> 
    <corners 
     android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" 
     android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="10dp" 
     android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>    
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that!
You can use a Shape Drawable to achieve that gradient effect.
The syntax for a Shape Drawable XML file can be found here :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Say you make a grad_bg.xml with the following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient android:angle="270" android:startColor="#00A4FF" android:endColor="#FFFFFF"/>
</shape>
```

Once you have your XML ready in the res/drawables/ folder of your app, you can set it as a background to and View element from layouts like LinearLayout to widgets like Buttons and TextViews using the following attribute in the view's tag :

```
android:background="@drawable/grad_bg"
```

or in code like this :

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grad_bg);
```

All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Just as an FYI, it's also possible to create gradients programmatically. Here is an example of a method you could use to return a linear gradient:

```
public static GradientDrawable createGradient(int startColor, int endColor, GradientDrawable.Orientation orientation) {
    GradientDrawable returnGradient;

    returnGradient =
            new GradientDrawable(
                    orientation,
                    new int[] {startColor, endColor}
            );

    return returnGradient;
}
```

And to call it:

```
int startColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.accent);
int endColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.primary);
GradientDrawable.Orientation orientation = GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM;

GradientDrawable gradient = createGradient(startColor, endColor, orientation);

myView.setBackground(gradient);
```